# How should I use tryCatch with warnErrList?

Tags: r

I am trying to catch any errors that might occur in my for loop, which will be repeating my function over and over again (the function itself is fine, but would just like to stress-test it to see if anything unexpected might pop out). I will run the for loop overnight and would like to wake up and see the list of errors.

However, I am unsure how should I use tryCatch in conjunction with warnErrList to produce such an effect...

```
stresstest <- for (i in 1:50000) tryCatch (
 {
    samplefunction(sampleargument)
 }
))

errorslist <- warnErrList(stresstest)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set the `error=` argument to `identity`. When you run `warnErrList` on the `res`ult thereafter, an error summary appears in a warning. *Example:*

```
x <- list(7, "a", 2, "c")

res <- sapply(x, function(x) 
  tryCatch({
    log(x)
  }, error=identity
  ))

warnErrList(res)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1.94591
# 
# [[2]]
# NULL
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 0.6931472
# 
# [[4]]
# NULL
# 
# attr(,"warningMsg")
# [1] "2 times caught the same error in log(x): non-numeric argument to mathematical function"
# Warning message:
#   2 times caught the same error in log(x): non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```